# Type mismatch error when using a function inside a sub

Tags: excel, vba

I've made a simple function which reads a string from an Excel cell and converts it into a formula:

```
Function f(x As Double) As Double
Dim q As String
q = Cells(2, 1)
formula = Replace(q, "x", x)
f = Evaluate(formula)
End Function
```

It works just fine when used in Excel. If, for example, the text in the cell (2, 1) is "x^2-6*x+15", the command "=f(1)" returns 10. However, when I try to use this function inside a sub, it returns a type mismatch error. I've tried to use this function in a following code for golden section search:

```
Sub goldenSectionSearch()
Dim k As Double, a As Double, b As Double, epsilon As Double, x1 As Double, x2 As Double
k = (Sqr(5) - 1) / 2

a = Cells(2, 2).Value
b = Cells(2, 3).Value
epsilon = Cells(2, 4).Value

x1 = b - k * (b - a)
x2 = a + k * (b - a)

Do While Abs(b - a) > epsilon
  If f(x1) > f(x2) Then
  a = x1
  x1 = x2
  x2 = a + k * (b - a)

  Else
  b = x2
  x2 = x1
  x1 = b - k * (b - a)
  End If
Loop

Cells(6, 2).Value = (a + b) / 2
Cells(7, 2).Value = f((a + b) / 2)
End Sub
```

After running the code line by line I seem to have pinpointed where the issue is, it happens right after the If, at the "a = x1" line. I'm afraid my lack of experience doesn't allow me to deduce why it's happening though.

Comment: I ran the code with some sample data, and it didn't generate an error, so the issue is probably data dependent. What are the values in B2:D2? Also, given that you don't explicitly reference a worksheet, I assume you're not swapping sheets such that it could be referencing the wrong one?

Comment: There's only one sheet. The data I'm using is a=0, b=10, epsilon=0,001, and the formula from Cells(2, 1) is x^2-6*x+15. I'm getting an error no matter what values I use though. I already had one person tell me they didn't encounter any problems with my code, could it be an issue with Excel 2013?

EDIT: Here's a proof it doesn't work for me: [Imgur link](https://imgur.com/a/95BMpfP)

Comment: Formula is the only variable you don't declare. Can you add prior to the evaluate a new line of code: debug.print typename(Formula), Formula   ... and see what it says. Could you declare Formula using Dim Formula as String and try running it again.

Comment: It says it's a String. Declaring it as such doesn't change anything either.

Comment: And what was the value of Formula just prior to the evaluate statement?

Comment: The contents of the immediate window are 
`String        6,18033988749895^2-6*6,18033988749895+15`

Comment: The only difference between your data and mine that I can see, is that your regional settings uses a comma to delimit the fractional part, but for me its a full stop (e.g. "1,1" vs "1.1"). The last thing that I can think of is forcing the numbers to use full stops to see whether that makes a difference, e.g.: f = Evaluate(Replace(Formula, ",", "."))

Comment: Oh. Oh my. I guess the weirdest solutions are the correct ones, huh? Thank you so very much.

Comment: VBA is US-centric in many respects.  I can reproduce your error if I set the comma as my decimal separator, but not if I set the dot as the decimal separator.